# Accessing every second row in matrix and save it to a new matrix, Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am new to python and struggling with the following problem.

I have a Matrix (6x2) and I want to save every second row into a new Matrix (3x2).

```
M = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]])
SM = []
for i in M(0,len(M),2):
  append.SM(i)
```

Is that even possible? Or do I have to split every single column first?
SM should then look like that:

```
SM = [[3,4],[7,8],[11,12]]
```

So far, I only found how to do that with a single column vector, that doesn't help, as I am not used to Python at all. 
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use slicing:

```
res = M[1::2,:]

print(res) 
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 7,  8],
       [11, 12]])
```

First  slice `1::2` means starting from position 1 until the end with step `2`. Second slice `:` to chose all elements in that level, i.e. rows.

If you need list at the end you could convert the `res` to list with `tolist` method:

```
print(res.tolist())
[[3, 4], [7, 8], [11, 12]]
```

Some more information about slicing you could find in [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Or as @lambo477 suggested in the comment you could just use:

```
M[1::2]
```

Which will give the same result

Comment: Note that you could just use `M[1::2]`